# Why do these t-sql batches behave differently?

Tags: sql-server

I am exploring the boundaries of Sql Server "batch" behavior in the presence of statement level problems. I read [this Technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175502(v=sql.105).aspx) and reproduced the example with some added experiments of my own.

I think I understand that SQL Server attempts compilation of a batch in two passes. The first pass is an attempt to compile every statement in the batch, which can fail in ways that might succeed later during execution using statement-level recompilation. In this case SQL Server will accept the batch and start executing it, attempting statement-level recompilation line by line as needed.

I don't understand why the following two examples behave differently.
I did this testing on SQL Server 2017 and 2008 R2 with identical results.

```
/* first example
   assuming table foo does not exist before first run 
*/
create table foo (i int);
insert into foo values (1);
insert into foo values (1,1);    /* wrong - column mismatch */
go
select * from foo;
```

1. First time this is run: result is a new table with one row (returned by select statement). Throws an error due to recompilation failure of second insert statement (i believe during second pass). `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.`
2. Second run: no change to the table. select statement still returns one row. Throws an error due to compilation failure of create table statement (i believe during first pass). `There is already an object named 'foo' in the database.`
3. Third run - this time with create table statement commented out: no change to the table. select still returns one row. Throws an error due to compilation failure of second insert statement (i believe during first pass this time). `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.`

Note that the error is exactly the same for the first and third runs, but that it occurs in different passes, so the batch behavior is different (by design).
This must be due to the fact that compilation of the statements following the create table statement in the first batch was delayed during the first run (which is the whole point of having a delayed statement-level recompilation facility).

Now - SURPRISINGLY - the following example behaves differently.

```
/* second example
   assuming tables foo and bar do not exist before first run 
*/
create table foo (i int);
insert into foo values (1);
insert into bar values (1,1);      /* wrong - different problem */
go
select * from foo;
```

1. First run: like the first example, table foo is created and has one row added. the select statement returns the single row. The error introduced in this case is: `Invalid object name ‘bar’` which is apparently caught during the second (recompilation) pass. So far the overall behavior is the same.
2. Second run: again same behavior - compilation fails (first pass) on the create table statement with the same error as in the first example.`There is already an object named 'foo' in the database.`  So again the overall behavior is the same.
3. Third run - this time with the create table statement commented out: **A new row is added to table foo**  then throws the same error (second pass) as in the first run: `Invalid object name ‘bar’.` I can rerun this over and over and a new row is added to table foo every time.

-- UPDATE --
A simplified example better demonstrates the effect of deferred name resolution after reading more about this (see tarheel's answer)

```
-- why does the first insert work in the first batch but not in the second?
-- because deferred name resolution forces the first batch
-- into a line-by-line compile+execute mode
create table foo (i int);
insert into foo values (1);       -- executes (row added to foo)
insert into foo values (1,1);     -- wrong columns, not detected on first pass
go
insert into foo values (1);       -- never executes
insert into foo values (1,1);     -- wrong columns, detected on first pass
go
select * from foo;
-- returns 1 row
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of [deferred name resolution](http://www.sommarskog.se/strict_checks.html#killDNR), where prior to running the batch only cares about valid syntax and does not check if the object (`bar`) itself exists.

In other words, because `foo` exists, the first batch sees that `insert into foo values (1,1);` is not valid syntax because of the existing table definition, and generates the error of `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition` before the first `insert` statement runs. While the second batch doesn't see the error until it looks for the object `bar` which is after the first `insert` statement runs.

You can get the second batch to behave the same way as the first by using `strict_checks` to look for the object `bar` prior to running any of the statements.

```
 SET STRICT_CHECKS ON
--create table foo (i int);
insert into foo values (1);
insert into bar values (1,1);      /* wrong - different problem */
go
select * from foo;
```

**Update:**

Another way of describing what is happening is this:

In the compilation phase, sql server assumes that the syntax is valid, unless it has evidence that the syntax is invalid. After validating the syntax, the batch enters the execution phase where it runs each line, and handles errors in order.

---

Batch 1 (third run - code before `GO`) compilation/execution would look like this:

1) Compile first insert (`insert into foo values (1);`) and see its valid syntax because it matches the `foo` schema.

2) Compile second insert (`insert into foo values (1,1);`) and see its not valid syntax because it does not match the `foo` schema. Raises Error.

3) Execute first insert - Never happens because of the error in step 2.

4) Execute second insert - Never happens because of the error in step 2.

---

Batch 2 (third run - code before `GO`) compilation/execution would look like this:

1) Compile first insert (`insert into foo values (1);`) and sees it's valid syntax because it matches the `foo` schema.

**2) Compile second insert (`insert into bar values (1,1);`) where there is no `bar` schema to check against, so it assumes that the syntax is valid and the `bar` table with the appropriate schema will be created before execution of the insert.**

3) Execute first insert, succeeds because it is valid syntax.

4) Execute second insert, Raises Error.

---

Batch 2, step 2 (in bold) is where the deferred name resolution comes into play.

Comment: i believe strict_checks is just a feature request - not part of t-sql. good link but i don’t see how it explains why my two examples behave differently. table foo exists in both cases.

Comment: @KevinOlree I have added further explanation in the answer above.

Comment: makes more sense to me now. i'm marking your answer as correct (i do suggest you edit out all refs to strict_checks. that code does not run).